# How much money to live "off-grid"?

Tags: money

How much money would you need to live off grid in a wooden hut in Alaska or somewhere else remote on Earth?

Let's presume we do this at 30 years old and live to 100.

Only costs I can think of are fuel (for generator), food and basic clothing, toiletries.

Comment: If your only costs other than fuel for the generator are food, basic clothing, and toiletries, what do you need the generator for?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone heating maybe..

Comment: Do you need healthcare?

Comment: Without health care? live to 100 years? I really doubt that... I think money is the least thing you will worry about.

Comment: @Aus You obviously haven't studied remote cultures so much :)

Comment: Not much, but you should be at least "on the grid" of some tribe.

Answer (score 0):

Your start up is expensive. Land remote. $10,000 U.S. for 2 hector. More for best ground. This is were you will be 100 & electric will still not come to you. Tools, $2,000. Water Buffalo $1,000. Pigs, chickens, goat. $200 for start up. $500 to build hut. Add $500 for extras. $2,000 a year for 3 years getting all going. Income $700 to $1,000 a year. If you work hard. Expenses $600 a year. Big expense is drilling a well. 2 inch pipe & sand point. Generator will bankrupt you. 1 solar plate only. Add 1 mountain girl, children buy 5 hector to start.  You will make out fine.

Comment: Can you re-write this answer in clear English please, not just bullet-pointed half - sentences?